# Tracking cart using cookie stopped working

Tags: shopify

Tacking a user's cart using the `cart` cookie isn't working for me anymore.

I've tested this on multiple sites, the cookie is no longer created when a product is added to the cart.

For example: http://www.fourcornerstore.com/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question a bit more? What are you trying to do, do you have any basic code you could share?

Comment: Sure, i'm talking about this functionality http://wiki.shopify.com/Tracking_Carts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It had to be disabled temporarily due to a bug, but will be reenabled as soon as possible. If you watch @shopifyapi on Twitter (I think you may have asked there as well), I'll make sure we let you guys know when the fix is deployed.